# Where can I download the Saxon validate example?

Tags: saxon

[In this question][1] it was recommended I look at the Saxon EE validate example. Where can I download it? It's not in [this] [2] or [this] [3].

```
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60252919/simple-code-to-verify-saxon-can-load-an-xml-file-and-optionally-schema?noredirect=1#comment106577884_60252919
  [2]: https://www.saxonica.com/download/saxon-resources9-9.zip
  [3]: https://www.saxonica.com/download/dotnet.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Martin Honnen may have answered your question in a comment on the original question?

The resources ZIP that you reference as `[2]` has folders `samples/java` and `samples/cs` with Java and C# examples respectively; both include sample code for invoking XSD validation. The C# version is at line 2550 of ExamplesEE.cs.

An alternative approach is to use a DocumentBuilder having first called setSchemaValidator() to make it do schema validation while building.

Comment: Yes he did. I was searching for validate.cs - it didn't occur to me that all the samples would be in a single file.